# MemSQL Schema Purpose in a MemSQL Database

Tags: singlestore

Does anyone know what the 'memsql' database / schema does in a MemSQL database?  This is the default schema that is automatically created when you start the service.  There are no tables, views, or routines in it and you can't create anything on it.  My best guess is that it's the equivalent of a 'Master' or 'msdb' database in SQL Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talked to the guys at MemSQL and the self-named schema 'memsql' is indeed the equivalent of 'master' on SQL Server